# Tag Times Error

Tags: equation-solving

Hello kind folks of stack exchange,

So I inherited the code below, and continually get the error:

```
Tag Times in Null {"Nicotine", "Lobeline", "DHBetaE", "Epibatidine", "Mecamylamine", "Varenicline"} is Protected.
```

Does anybody know how to fix this? I've seen similar problems posted elsewhere but as a mathematica novice was unable to interpret the results. Any help would be appreciated. (Frankly, I just want to generate six plots using the plethora of constants above, most of which are fully ignorable, but mathematica seems to have other plans).

```
cEvalues = {-27, -10, -1, 1, 10, 27};

For[cEi = 1, cEi <= 6, cEi++,

 M = {162, 337, 275, 209, 167, 211};      
 k5 = {8.*^-6, 4.*^-6, 0.3*^-3, 0.01*^-6, 0.001, 0.4*^-6}; 
 Ki = k5*1*^6; 
 Lkn1 = {1, 4, 2.2, 1.73, 2.57, 1.4};      
 Lki1 = {-3, 0.91, -0.97, -3, -0.53, -1.7};   
 kn1 = 10^Lkn1;
 ki1 = 10^Lki1;
 pkaw = {8, 8.6, 7.3, 9.5, 11.2, 9.6};    
 pkam = pkaw - 1;     
 v = 1;    
 i = 1;    
 cic = ConstantArray[0, 6];  
 cil = 0.1*^-6*M*100;
 Cy = 0.1;
 co = 0; 
 vc = 1.41*^-14;
 vl = 1.68*^-19/64; 
 ac = 2.83*^-9;  
 al = 5.03*^-12/16; 
 phc = 7;
 pho = 7.4;
 phl = 5;
 L = 0.05;
 W = 0.95;
 Ec = -7*^-2;

 cE = cEvalues[[cEi]];
 El = cE*(1*^-2); 

 F = 96484.56; 
 R = 8.312; 
 T = 293.15; 
 dcell = 2*^-9*Sqrt[32./M]; 
 dx = 0.001; 
 pnm = 10^(Lkn1 - 6.7); 
 paq = dcell/dx; 
 pn = 1/((1./pnm) + (1./paq));  
 pdm = 10^(Lki1 - 6.7); 
 pdg = 1/((1./pdm) + (1./paq));      
 fon = 1/(1 + 10^(i*(pkam - pho))); 
 fod = 1 - fon;  
 kin1 = L*1.22*kn1; 
 kd1 = L*1.22*ki1; 
 yn = 1.23;
 yd = 0.738; 
 d1 = 10^(i*(pkam - phc));      
 fni = 1/(W/yn + kin1/yn + d1*W/yd + d1*kd1/yd);
 fdi = fni*d1; 
 N1 = v*Ec*F/(R*T); 
 N2 = v*El*F/(R*T);    
 Eoi = fon*pn + fod*pdg*N1/(Exp[N1] - 1);
 Eio = fni*pn + fdi*pdg*Exp[N1]*N1/(Exp[N1] - 1);  
 pn2 = 10^(Lkn1 - 6.7); 
 pd2 = 10^(Lki1 - 6.7);
 Eil = fni*pn2 + fdi*pd2*N2/(Exp[N2] - 1); 
 d2 = 10^(i*(pkam - phl)); 
 kin2 = L*1.22*kn1; 
 kd2 = L*1.22*ki1;
 fln = ConstantArray[0, 6]; 
 fld = ConstantArray[1, 6]; 
 Eli = fln*pn2 + fld*pd2*Exp[N2]*N2/(Exp[N2] - 1);
 I1 = ac/vc*co*Eoi; 
 a11 = (ac/vc)*Eio + (al/vc)*Eil; 
 a12 = al/vc*Eli; 
 a21 = al/vl*Eil; 
 a22 = al/vl*Eli; 
 Bmax = 35.6 ;      
 a23 = ConstantArray[3*^-3, 6];  
 a32 = ConstantArray[7.4*^-4, 6]; 

 (*Equations*)
 Model = ConstantArray[c, {6, 4}];
 For[i = 1, i <= 6, i++, 
   Model[[i]] = {{x'[t] == I1[[i]] - a11[[i]]*x[t] + a12[[i]]*y[t], 
      y'[t] == (-a22[[i]] - a23[[i]]*fld[[i]])*y[t] + a21[[i]]*x[t] + 
        a32[[i]]*z[t], 
      z'[t] == -a32[[i]]*z[t] + a23[[i]]*fld[[i]]*y[t]}, {x[0] ==  
       cic[[i]], y[0] == 0.5* cil[[i]], z[0] == 0.5*cil[[i]]}}]

  s = ConstantArray[c, 6];
 For[i = 1, i <= 6, i++,
    s[[i]] = DSolve[Model[[i]], {x, y, z}, {t, 0, 60000}]]
   p = {"Nicotine", "Lobeline", "DHBetaE", "Epibatidine", 
   "Mecamylamine", "Varenicline"};
 lambda = {Thickness[0.002]}

   (*Plot Fractional Mass in the Cell vs. Time*)

   Plot [Evaluate[(y[60 t]*vl + x[60 t]*vc + z[60 t]*vl)/(y[0]*vl + 
         x[0]*vc + z[0]*vl) /. s], {t, 0, 1000}, 
    PlotRange -> {0, 1.1}, ImageSize -> {1000}, 
    PlotTheme -> "VibrantColor", 
    AxesLabel -> {"time(minutes)", "fraction of origial"}, 
    PlotLabel -> "Fractional Mass in the Cell vs. Time", 
    PlotLegends -> 
     Placed[SwatchLegend[p, LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 26}, 
       LegendMarkerSize -> 30], {Right, Top}], 
    BaseStyle -> {FontWeight -> "Normal", FontSize -> 35}, 
    PlotStyle -> Thickness[0.004], AxesStyle -> Directive[Black, 30], 
    RotateLabel -> True
   ]

 ]
```

Comment: Use a semicolon after the `For` loop

Comment: In particular the `For` loop right before `p = {"Nicotine", ...}`.